# Mathematics of Waves, Interpretation of Sine wave as a function of $x$

Tags: waves

[image]

The second equation of the image above shows the position $y$, which describes the position $y$ of a wave function given an input $x$. Furthermore, we now want to see the wave is traveling over time.

Hence,

$\sin(\delta x)$

$\delta x = x_{f} - x_{i}$

Because of the relationship of $\delta x$, I would argue:

$y(x,t) = A\sin(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(vt-x))$

If I am looking at my Physics textbook on the topic of the mathematical equations of waves, it looks as if we are calculating the opposite position in the $y$-direction using our $x$ and $t$ input.

Let's go back to finding the position $y$ using degrees as an input:

$A\sin(90 - 0) = A(1)$

vs

$A\sin(0-90) = A(-1)$

Here I can see that it would make more sense to have the position initial be subtracted from position final to see how the position in $y$ changes at $\theta$ degrees.

Does anyone know if my argument is not sound and why?

Comment: The position $x=v\,t$ tracts a node in the wave where $y=0$. The node position changes linearly with time. So what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to think about these sorts of signs is usually to freeze the wave at time $t=0$ and see what happens.

In your convention the function reduces to $$
\begin{align}
y(x, 0) & = A \sin\left(-2\pi\frac x\lambda\right)\\
&= -A \sin\left(2\pi\frac x\lambda\right),
\end{align}
$$
whereas in their convention the leading term is $+$ not $-$.

Ultimately both represent the exact same family of equations, one will just have negative $A$ when the other has positive $A$ and vice versa. In fact, your preference is more common among electrical engineers, who often like to deal with complex numbers by defining that $j=\sqrt{-1}$ and then the complex rotation whose real projection is a wave is usually written $e^{j(\omega t - k x)}.$ I know physicists who resolve this terminology difference in an amusing way, they say that which square root of $-1$ you choose (there are two of them) is arbitrary, and physicists and engineers have chosen the opposite ones so that $i=-j$, hah.

Physicists are more likely to describe it as $kx-\omega t$, though. I am personally very weird and I hate writing parentheses in the exponent so I define the default argument of 1 as $1 = e^{2\pi i}$ and then write absurd things like $1^{x/\lambda - f t}$, or sometimes in my notes I write it *ə* or so. If I ever got back into physics and wanted to publish, my PhD advisor would likely smack me upside the head and tell me to write it a normal way.

Comment: That was beautifully written. It makes sense in my mind now. Thank you, kind sir!! xDD